# Java parseInt() question

Tags: java, parseint

Why is it that when I use parseInt for this:

```
private String certainNumber;

public int getNumber()
{
    return Integer.parseInt(certainNumber);
}
```

It compiles.

But If I were to do this:

```
public String getStreetNumber()
{
    return streetNumber;
}
```

and parseInt the returned value like so:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) 
{
    Address tempAddress = (Address)o;
    if(Integer.parseInt(getStreetNumber()) < tempAddress.Integer.parseInt(getStreetNumber()))
    {
        return -1;
    }
... // etc.
}
```

It does not compile?

edit: tried the suggestions... still not compiling?

edit2: Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Beacause you are calling parseInt directly, You must use Integer.parseInt() as it it is an static method of Integer class

Comment: what is Address? does it have a method parseInt()?

Comment: If you wanted to, you could statically import the `parseInt` method.

Answer (score 4):

That is because `parseInt` is a method which belongs to the `Integer` class: you have to call it `Integer.parseInt(value);`. I highly doubt that you have a parseInt function in either your custom class (I suspect that this is all part of an Address class?) or the tempAddress instance.

Try this:

```
public int compareTo(Object o) 
{
    Address tempAddress = (Address)o;
    if(Integer.parseInt(getStreetNumber()) < 
          // you need to parse the return value of tempAddress's getStreetNumber() 
          // not get the tempAddress's parseInt of this.getStreetNumber()
          Integer.parseInt(tempAddress.getStreetNumber()))
    {
        return -1;
    }
 // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you called `parseInt()` not `Integer.parseInt()`

Answer (score 2):

[`parseInt`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) is a static method in the [`Integer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) class. You call it as 
`Integer.parseInt(the_string_you_want_to_parse)`

If you want to parse an string returned by a method in another class you call it as
`Integer.parseInt(tempAddress.getStreetNumber())`

Answer (score 1):

Others answered your direct question, but let me say that this is a very clean way of doing the same thing you're trying to do:

```
return Integer.valueOf(getStreetNumber())
    .compareTo(
       Integer.valueOf(tempAddress.getStreetNumber()));
```

`Integer` already implements `Comparable`, so you might as well leverage it.

Answer (score 0):

`if(Integer.parseInt(getStreetNumber())`

Answer (score 0):

How can you call a parseInt on a Address reference???

- > if(parseInt(getStreetNumber()) < tempAddress.parseInt(getStreetNumber()))

Also you should always say Integer.parseInt(), you cant call the parseInt directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can also statically import it:

```
import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;
```